# MySQL - Retrieve results even if join is null

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following sql working with 1 minor issue that I need help with. I am needing the results to show even if one of the joined tables is null. I have tried using a left/right join, but it didn't seem to make a difference, what do I need to use to make this work?

As it is now, the query will work unless the record in the table dx_code_patient has no match, I need it show the results even if there are no matching records in that table.

```
SELECT
 group_concat(distinct current_dx.dx_code_with, ': ', current_dx.description SEPARATOR ' - ') AS current_dxc, 
 group_concat(distinct pending_dx.dx_code_with, ': ', pending_dx.description SEPARATOR ' - ') AS pending_dxc,
 p.id, p.first_name, p.last_name
 FROM patients AS p
 INNER JOIN tmp_dx_code_patient AS tmp_dx
   ON tmp_dx.patient_id = p.id    
 INNER JOIN dx_code_patient AS cdx 
   ON cdx.patient_id = p.id
 INNER JOIN dx_codes AS current_dx
   ON current_dx.id = cdx.dx_code_id
 INNER JOIN dx_codes AS pending_dx
   ON pending_dx.id = tmp_dx.dx_code_id
 GROUP BY p.id
 ORDER BY tmp_dx.created_at asc
```

current results:

```
+----------------+--------------+----+------------+-----------+
| current_dxc    | pending_dxc  | id | first_name | last_name |
+----------------+--------------+----+------------+-----------+
| def: something | 123: message |  2 | Bob        | Smith     |
+----------------+--------------+----+------------+-----------+
```

Expected

```
+----------------+---------------+----+------------+------------+
| current_dxc    | pending_dxc   | id | first_name | last_name  |
+----------------+---------------+----+------------+------------+
| null           | ghy: hi       |  1 |       Mike |      Jones |
+----------------+---------------+----+------------+------------+
| def: something | 123: message  |  2 |        Bob |      Smith |
+----------------+---------------+----+------------+------------+
| null           | 432: question |  3 |       John |        Doe |
+----------------+---------------+----+------------+------------+
```

Comment: Have you tried a Full Join?

Comment: @Hiren Patel mysql does not have FULL JOIN it has to be simulated..

Comment: I guess you tried to change only 1 of your joins to left join. Change them all.

Comment: @Strawberry I updated my question to best reflect your post... I thought my question was pretty straightforward, but then again I know what I'm wanting in my results. thanks (Hopefully you didn't down vote it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JOIN` does not return `NULL` results.  My guess is that you mean no rows match.  If so, a `LEFT JOIN` should solve your problem.  Use it throughout the `FROM` clause:

```
FROM patients p LEFT JOIN
    tmp_dx_code_patient  tmp_dx
    ON tmp_dx.patient_id = p.id LEFT JOIN  
    dx_code_patient cdx 
    ON cdx.patient_id = p.id LEFT JOIN
    dx_codes current_dx
    ON current_dx.id = cdx.dx_code_id LEFT JOIN
    dx_codes pending_dx
    ON pending_dx.id = tmp_dx.dx_code_id
```

Comment: Thank you, that was it, I only tried the left join on the one table, didn't know it had to be on all!